# How do I convince my parents to get me a pet

Tags: pets

I’ve really wanted a ferret ever since I saw one at the pet store. I’ve done alot of research on them and I think I can handle it, but I know my parents will probably say no. Is there a way I could convince them to get me one? Sorry if this isn’t the right kind of site this is my first time asking.

Comment: Where will said ferret live?  Will it be in your parents' house, or are you on your own with a place for pets?

Comment: Hi Snowball! This may be the right site, but please take a look at our [good question guidelines](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3224/1599) and our [help/on-topic]. We ask that questions include some details, like how you've behaved so far in trying to convince them, or why you think certain kinds of behavior won't work when convincing your parents. We also request you include the arguments you'd like to present to your parents, as we're not here to settle disputes or make up arguments for you. Could you [edit] your post to include the necessary details?

Comment: You do know that ferrets are [smelly](https://animals.mom.me/ferrets-stink-1649.html), don't you?

Answer (score 2):

Having raised children, and I can tell you what works and what doesn’t work from the [parenting perspective](http://guerillaparentingbyyosefbaskin.blogspot.com).

You have to think through what objections your parents might have, say five items. If you can anticipate their objections, you can be ready with decent responses.

> Whining doesn’t work, logic does. Badgering doesn’t work, but eliminating objections does. Find some quiet time when your parents are in a good mood. You might have to wait.

1. In your own words, tell them there’s something you want to talk about, which warns them there’s a whole story coming ... and not to interrupt so fast.
2. Tell them you want a ferret, and you’ve done your research to know in fact that you can handle it.
3. Here’s the ace up your sleeve: your final point becomes, again in your own words, is there something that I can do to earn it?

> Parents are human, they will be blown away by the maturity of your plan.